# Initiate connection from Arduino to remote device

Tags: bluetooth, arduino

I am trying to achieve that my arduino-built device connects automatically to a device after it is switched on. The board is an Arduino Mini Pro and the bluetooth module is the Bluetooth Mate Silver (RN42). The devices are already paired, the bluetooth module is in slave mode, the remote device (in this case a normal laptop) is discoverable. I am using the SoftwareSerial library provided with the Arduino software.

Here is my setup:

```
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);  // Begin the serial monitor at 9600bps

  // bluetooth

  // set baud rate to 9600 
  bluetooth.begin(9600);  
  // start command mode
  bluetooth.print("$$$");
  // reply delay
  delay(100);
  // set to slave mode
  bluetooth.println("SM,0");
  // reply delay
  delay(100);
  // set device pin to 0403
  bluetooth.println("SP,0403");
  // reply delay
  delay(100);
  // connect to pixelsense
  bluetooth.println("C," + remoteMAC); // remoteMAC is a string with the mac address
  // reply delay
  delay(2500);
  // leave command mode
  bluetooth.println("---");
  // reply delay
  delay(100);
}
```

I read the command set of the RN42 and I think the commands are correct. I can connect to Arduino via bluetooth but the other direction isn't working. I also tried using the master mode or storing the remote mac in the flash instead of using a string. From the documentation it should be possible to initiate connections from the RN42, but I haven't quite found out how this works in details. Can anyone provide any help to solve my issue?

EDIT: The device does not seem to enter command mode at all. At least the flash lights don't indicate that. Is there anything wrong with the commands so that the command mode cannot be accessed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After nearly a week, I came across a solution. Actually it seems to be important that there is any program that accepts a bluetooth connection. I tried it the whole time with the Windows 7 Bluetooth dialog menu entry "Receive a file" but that did not work. So I used a third party program that listens for incoming connections and that actually worked. Basically everything I did was fine except for the missing connection listener.

Sometimes if I upload new code to the Arduino there is the problem that the connection cannot be established. This can be solved by removing and readding the bluetooth device.

The code for the RN42 Bluetooth Client above works. The library [SoftwareSerial](http://arduino.cc/de/Reference/SoftwareSerial) provided with the Arduino software is used.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to put some delay after bluetooth.begin(9600), to let set its baudrate and then issue print command.

Comment: Did not work. I think the main problem is that the device isn't even entering the command mode. The flash light simply indicates that the device is in discoverable mode (1 blink/sec)...

Comment: May you can try numbers of suggestion listed in this discussion. https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/264. Or Try different baudrate

Comment: It seems to prevent a lot of trouble if you program your bluetooth device via a separate remote connection and not via Arduino program code. Also `ST,255` is a good helper because the bluetooth device is not resetted if new program code is uploaded and so it won't switch to command mode (must be done within 60 seconds after startup by default). But the main problem (automatic connect) is still not solved...

Answer (score 0):

You can enter into the **command mode only in 60s after the module is powered on**. You can see if the timer is still counting using the status LED(**if it blink 2 per second**). Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Code would be helpful

Comment: This is the default settings. I changed this as soon as I found out how :)

Answer (score 0):

On startup the RN-42 needs 500ms before it can enter command mode try 'delay(500);' before 'bluetooth.begin(115200);' and that should get you there. Also CTS should be tied low

as can be seen on page 45 of the document found at the link below.

https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/1/e/e/5/d/5217b297757b7fd3748b4567.pdf

PG 45

"3.3 INTERFACING TO A MICROPROCESSOR
Roving Networks Bluetooth devices can connect to 3.3-V (only) microprocessors using
the UART interface. When interfacing with a microprocessor, use the following guidelines:
• The Bluetooth device power, ground, RX, and TX signals must be connected and
***CTS should be held low*** or tied to RTS.
• ***The Bluetooth device can go into command mode 500 ms after booting.***
• The microprocessor should send $$$ with no carriage return or line feed to enter
command mode.
3.3.0.1 HOW DO I KNOW THE MODULE IS READY FOR COMMAND MODE?
***500 ms after rebooting***, the module is ready for command mode. You send $$$with no
carriage return.
3.3.0.2 WHICH HARD SIGNALS SHOULD I CONNECT?
You should connect power, ground, RX, and TX. ***CTS should be low*** or you can connect
or tie it to RTS."